Garage framing falling off foundation
I moved into my home last year and our detached garage has one side that is falling off the foundation. The whole garage is raised off a slab with cement blocks and the back side has pushed off the center of the blocks.
I have filled in gaps with spray foam to prevent any animals from slipping in but is there concern of collapsing? The remaining walls are solid on the center of the blocks and the back only bows out in the center but it is bowed out about an inch at the max.

Please edit the pictures using the Edit link for your question, then the Mountain icon. We'd definitely want them visible here.

Without knowing the reasons for the displacement or the details of the wall I can only offer general advice.

As long as there's at least 1½" of bearing and the block is still in stable position there's probably no real risk of collapse.

The back wall of a garage is often a gable wall, which typically doesn't carry load aside from itself. If that's the case here, even if the framing came completely off the block it might not drop at all.

Assuming the displacement was due to sloppy driving, this can probably be rectified fairly easily. You don't want to just pound it back in place, since that might dislodge the blocks, but you can probably do some jacking of the wall and swing it back into position. A leg under the top plate(s) might work for that. Once it's back in position, consider adding anchor bolts.


